# How do I loop this in javascript?

Tags: javascript

So I have an onclick event and then another event on the same click. Basic function works like this:

1) Click image - Zoom 700%
2) Click image again - Zoom 100%
3) Click image again - Zoom 100%

I want step 3 to revert back to step 1 and then to 2 etc. Right now, it just repeats step 2 forever instead of reverting back to default.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".zoomTarget").debug();
    $(window).resize(function(evt) {
        $(".zoomTarget").debug();
    });
    $(".zoomTarget").click(function(evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        $(this).zoomTo({
            targetsize: 5.0
        }); {
            $(".zoomTarget").click(function(evt) {
                evt.stopPropagation();
                $("body").zoomTo({
                    targetsize: 1.0
                });
            });
        }
    });
    $(document).click(function(evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        $("body").zoomTo({
            targetsize: 1.0
        });
    });
    $("body").zoomTo({
        targetsize: 1.0
    });
};
```

Comment: I think you want this: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: What's with the superfluous block statement? `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would use a boolean inside the `ready` function to keep track of what state I'm in, and then toggle it inside the handler:

```
var zooming_in=true;
$(".zoomTarget").click(function(evt) {
     evt.stopPropagation();
     $(this).zoomTo({
          targetsize: (zooming_in=!zooming_in)?5.0:1.0
     });
});
```

Comment: You can't use the keyword "in" as a variable. That nullifies this entire code. But thanks for the answer though.

Comment: You get the idea, I'll update with a better name. Wouldn't say it "nullifies" it, the concept is fine, just needs a new variable name...